# Admin language module

Tags: 7, users, i18n-l10n, navigation

I'm currently building websites with the [Administration Language](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_language) Module. For the first time, the admin language is different than the default language but it doesn't work. For example, my default language is English and I'll set Spanish for the admin menu. My admin menu (and all administration dashboard) is partially translate.

As you can see, sometime item's menu are in English and in Spanish.

> [image: Admin menu lang]

However, "People" is correctly translate in Translate Admin.

> [image: People translation available]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Visit admin/config/regional/language and select an admin language
2. Visit admin/config/regional/language/admin_language and enable *Use administration language for the core toolbar*

Comment: I trying but doesn't work. I am still searching in different patch on drupal.org.
Thanks for your help.